# Can an updated with nested select be considered atomic in Sybase?

Tags: sql, sybase, atomic

I am trying something like this:

```
set rowcount 10 //fetch only 10 row
Update tableX set x=@BatchId where id in (select id from tableX where x=0)
```

basically mark 10 record as booked by supplying a batchId. 
So my question is if this proc is executed in parallel then can I guarantee that update with select will be atomic and no invocation will select similar setof record from tableX for booking?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To guarantee that no such overlaps occur, yo should:
(i) put BEGIN TRANSACTION - COMMIT around the statement
(ii) put the HOLDLOCK keyword directly behind 'tableX' (or run the whole statement at isolation level 3).

Comment: So as per your comment either use one of the three or use all three?

Comment: understood..I giess u wanted to say this:http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.dc20021_1251/html/locking/locking23.htm

Comment: isolation level 3 as described here has meaning only inside the scope of a transaction, So you need to use them both. 'holdlock' == isolation level 3 for that particular table only.

Comment: WHen I a, using holdlock then I am getting a deadlock situation.holdlock is used on only one table